# how to pass datagridview value to another form when the datagridviewbutton cell is clicked

Tags: c#, datagridview

I've been working on my datagridview properties and wondering how can I pass the value of my selected data row to another form.

```
private void dgvRptView_CellContentClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
        var senderGrid = (DataGridView)sender;
        if (senderGrid.Columns[e.ColumnIndex] is DataGridViewButtonColumn &&
            e.RowIndex >= 0)
        {

                Form Update = new frmUpdateSvcRep();
                Update.Show();
        }
     }
```

apparently, I was only able to add button inside the datagridview and added an event when I clicked the button, it'll show a form. However. I've been trying to pass the values I selected to textbox in another from but to no avail. Can someone please help me figure out how to pass the value where I click my button? here's my image caption.

[image: How to pass the values of my current selected row to another form]

here's my another form looks like when I click the edit button inside the Datagridview.

[image: how can I pass the value in the rows I selected]

I'm really out of my depth for now.. I'm opt on creating constructors but I don't know how to implement it in this Scenario. Thanks in Advance

Comment: SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter();
                da.SelectCommand = cmd;
                DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                da.Fill(dt);

                if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
                {
                    dgvRptView.DataSource = dt;
                    
                } "i assigned datatable to populate my datas to datagridview"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several ways to accomplish passing data between Forms. One way, as you mentioned, is to pass via the constructor when you instantiate the Form:

```
private void dgvRptView_CellContentClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    if (dgvRptView.Columns[e.ColumnIndex] is DataGridViewButtonColumn &&
        e.RowIndex >= 0)

    if (dgvRptView.CurrentRow != null)
    {
        var row = dgvRptView.CurrentRow.Cells;

        DateTime age = Convert.ToDateTime(row["MyColumn"].Value);
        string name = Convert.ToString(row["MyName"].Value);

        Form Update = new frmUpdateSvcRep(age, name);
        Update.Show();
    }
}
```

Update the constructor of your other Form to accept those parameters:

```
public class Update : Form
{
    public Update(DateTime age, string name)
    {
        // do whatever you want with the parameters
    }

    ...
}
```

It might be tempting to just pass the entire `dgvRptView.CurrentRow` object, but I'd advise against that. Your other Form then has to know about the columns in the DataGridView so it can access the values, which is not something it should be concerned about and could lead to runtime bugs when the column names change.

Comment: Ok, i'll give it a shot.

Comment: I Got it. but im having a hard time identifying what property datetimepicker belongs to? can you help me?

Comment: do you see the "time finish" in the image above?. I don't know what the extension of that if to be pass by a value. would that be a dtp.Text or dtp.Value?