# how to pass datagridview record to another form C Sharp and SQL server

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2022

i'm new in this..
I have datagridview in Form2 and Form in Form1.
tell me Basic things to pass  data from DataGridView to another Form in Visual Studio 2022.

Comment: Are you working with Windows Forms? Can you please elaborate on what exactly you need?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how to pass datagridview value to another form when the datagridviewbutton cell is clicked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28468296/how-to-pass-datagridview-value-to-another-form-when-the-datagridviewbutton-cell)